# Handlebarsjs Array of Objects: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have a list of items and each item can have a `Photo` item or not.

I'm looping using `this`.

It is fine when all items have a `Photo`:

```
<script id='library-template' type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#this}}
        <div class='box'>
            <a href='#insight' data-insight_id="{{Item.id}}">
            {{#if Photo.0.id }}
                    {{Photo.0.photo}}
            {{/if}}
            </a>

            <div class='subtitle'>
                <h2>{{Item.title}}</h2>
                <p>Added: {{Item.created}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/this}}
</script>
```

When the current object do not have a Photo object:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Format of my objects:

```
[  
Object  
    Item: Object  
    Photo: Array[1]  
    Rating: Array[0]  
    Tag: Array[0]  
    __proto__: Object  
,
Object  
    Item: Object  
    Photo: Array[0]  
    Rating: Array[0]  
    Tag: Array[0]  
    __proto__: Object  
,
Object  
,
Object  
,
Object  
]
```

The second object does not have a `Photo` record all the other ones do.

How can I access the Photo object making sure an error won't be raised when Photo has no content?

Note: testing {{#if Photo.0}} instead of {{#if Photo.0.id}} results:
Error: Parse error on line 5: ...}">     {{#if Photo.0 }}    {{Photo.0 ----------------------^ Expecting 'ID'

Comment: Fixed: Adding here in case someone runs in the same issue:      {{#if Photo.length}}
      {{Photo.0.photo}}
    {{/if}}

Answer (score 4):

Putting here in case somebody else need:

```
 {{#if Photo.length}} {{Photo.0.photo}} {{/if}}
```